# Stuck on image in an Advanced Custom Field loop

Tags: plugins

```
  <?php

  // check if the repeater field has rows of data
  if( have_rows('tool_card') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
      while ( have_rows('tool_card') ) : the_row();

          // display a sub field value
          the_sub_field('title');

          <img src="<?php the_sub_field('tool_image');?>">

      endwhile;

  else :

      // no rows found

  endif;

  ?>
```

The above image doesn't load when using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields...

I know I am doing something a bit dumb but I can't figure it out. If anyone is familiar with the plugin I'd really appreciate a pointer here...

Thanks

All solutions VERY welcomed, thank you

Comment: when you registered the image field, what did you set the return value as?

Answer (score 1):

This may be obvious, but the issue is in `<img src="<?php the_sub_field('tool_image');?>">`.

`the_sub_field('field_name')` will output the field's content, which I think in your case will be an image tag. In your case you should use `get_sub_field('field_name')`. using the `get_` will return the value. Returning the value will be handy for #1 below.

I haven't looked at ACF Pro docs for a bit, but try this:

**1.)** if you've set the image field return value as an `array`:

```
<?php
$image = get_sub_field('tool_image');
?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
```

***Please keep in mind that this is a basic example. The returned array will give you all the correct sizes/urls. By combing through that data you'll be able to get the expected/appropriate image size/url.

**2. )** If you've set the image return value to be the ID.

```
<?php
$image = get_sub_field('tool_image');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $image ) {
  echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}
```

[You can find the docs here.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Comment: Another issue which you solved but didn't explicitly state: `... the_sub_field('title');
          <img src="<?php the_sub_fi...` is not valid PHP